# HP ML10v2 - Power Failure - Critical Temperature

Tags: hp, electrical-power, ilo

I received an ML10v2 today.  I haven't installed any HDDs yet but have installed a SATA optical drive which is connected directly to the m-board.

The server doesn't boot and doesn't produce a video output, iLO shows critical system health - 'Critical Temperature Threshold Exceeded' which it most defiantly is not.

What has failed and what can I do to fix it?  Is the best option to send it back?

Cheers,
Fred.

Comment: Can you disconnect the SATA optical drive and try again?

Comment: Have tried this, disconnected drive from power and removed the SATA cable from both ends, still get the same problem.  Also - all of the temperature readings show as 0C when viewing iLO.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this it should be directed to the vendor rather than SF.

Comment: I would just like to add that the fault was caused by a bad ambient temperature sensor.  The system will boot with the sensor removed and a replacement is on the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a situation where you should contact your vendor. If this is a new system, it makes sense to call whoever sold you the system *or* you have the option of contacting HP support.

Feel free to check for loose components: fans, CPU heatsinks, etc.

But in the end, it sounds like this machine is DOA.

Comment: Thanks, I thought this was the case but hoped that I wouldn't have to go through the hassle of returning it.  But obviously it is the best way to go.